# How to dynamically assign an internal DNS server to an internal client that receives dynamic IP information from an external DHCP server?

Tags: networking, internal-dns, dynamic-ip

My question title sums up everything, what I am trying to archive here is – when an internal client (laptop in the network diagram picture) joins the internal L3 switch on the Lab side, it should dynamically receive the internal DNS server IP instead of external university DNS server IP. I can modify the Lab side network and add any necessary network device, only catch is all devices are need to be dynamically assigned by external DHCP server and should reside in same university network except the statically assigned internal DNS server.

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z46L1.png)